# My Angular js app dpesn't work when i put my controller in a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="customersApp">
    <head>
        <title>Angular js Hello World</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-init="">

    <h2>Customers</h2>

    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name">
    <br><br>{{name}}
    <span class="pre-search">Your Search:</span>&nbsp;<span class="search-term">{{customerFilter.name}}</span>
    <br><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reversed">
            <td>{{cust.name | lowercase}}</td>
            <td>{{cust.city}}</td>
            <td>{{cust.orderTotal | currency}}</td>
            <td>{{cust.joined | date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <span>Total Customers : {{customers.length}}</span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

and my app/app.js:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('customersApp', []);
}());
```

and also my app/controllers/CustomersController.js:

```
(function () {
angular.module('customersApp')
    .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.sortBy = 'name';
        $scope.reversed = false;
        $scope.name = "Ramachandra";

        $scope.customers = [{joined:'1984-06-29', name:'Virat Kohli', city:'banglore', orderTotal:'90.9468'}, {joined:'1920-03-19', name:'Yuvraj Singh', city:'vijayawada', orderTotal:'300.454'}, {joined:'1980-08-03', name:'MS Dhoni', city:'katamnallur', orderTotal:'35.78'}, {joined:'2010-01-23', name:'Michael Jordan', city:'Hoskote', orderTotal:'45.10'}];
        $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
            $scope.sortBy = propName; 
            $scope.reversed =! $scope.reversed;
        };
    });
}());
```

Now when i just put in my controller script src in html and call that controller alone, it goes just fine, when i just put around a few lines to make it a part of module, it goes off, thanks for answering.

Comment: i think you are  missing the module dependency array in a lineangular.module('customersApp').As i read in tutorials it should be angular.module('customersApp',[ ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you miss the controller import?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/CustomersController.js"></script>
```

right after the app.js import

Comment: also `ng-controller="CustomersController"` should be there on body tag

Comment: just a sec, cz i feel i have tried those, but again i will do that and see what happens and post here

Comment: I put Controller src and ng-controller..... but no luck guys FYI it even broke more it displays all the {{ <- curly brackets and stuff to screen.

Comment: I tried your code in a fiddle (except that js code isn't split into two files, but with your module separation): https://jsfiddle.net/scratch_cf/z3hngs5z/

Comment: 13:49:05.298 "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CustomersController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/ng/areq?p0=CustomersController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
minErr/<@file:///home/ajay/Desktop/learning/angular/End/assets/js/angular.js:78:12

Comment: so how can i make this work when seperated, what may make this code work??

Comment: Maybe the issue is the way we inject the controller which have changed since angular 1.3 I think.
If you try that way to declare your controller, maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/scratch_cf/z3hngs5z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry to even say this guys after a lot of play around i found one of my file being named wrong in the src attribute, Sincere thankyou to Mickael R and pankaj parkar for being with me, really sorry, 


**If any one else is looking for answers and viewing this try looking for all the files being named and referenced right in the html file**